# Terminal in VSCode showing blank screen in Ubuntu 18

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, visual-studio-code, gnome-terminal

I am having this issue with VScode for a long time now. The terminal shows a blank screen with a pointer and i am not able to type anything. I tried all kinds of solutions like restarting terminal, resizing, deleting and opening terminal restarting Vscode again but it doesn't work at all.
Here is the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue with VS Code in Ubuntu and fixed it with: `File -> Preferences -> Setting -> Features -> Terminal -> Inherit Env`

Comment: You are a savior @DuDoff

Comment: I already have this enabled by default, if someone comes up with a solution - this only happens to me on system wake-up - if I restart terminal it is okay again, just annoying.

Comment: @MichalFašánek, try   `"terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off"` in settings.json